# Django sitemap index example

Tags: django, sitemap

I have following models relation:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    section = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = True)


class Article (models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 30, unique=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField()  
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
```

I need to create a sitemap for articles, which contains sitemap files for sections. I was reading django documentation about it here http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/

But didn't manage to find answer how can I:

1. Define sitemap class in this case
2. How can I pass section parameters into url file (as it's explained in
   the docs)
3. From where can I get {'sitemaps': sitemaps} if I defined
   sitemap as a python class in another file in the application

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. 1. Define it as described in the docs. What are you not clear about? 2. What parameters? What url file - do you mean urls.py? This has nothing to do with a sitemap. 3. You import it, like you would with any other code that you define in a different file.

Comment: But, to create a section sitemap I need to implement filter.
Something like this:
Acrticle.objects.filter(section = Section.objects.get(section = section))

Not sure where should I implement the filter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to use sitemap index that would point at seperate sitemap xml files each for every section.

Django supports this feature by [providing a separate sitemap view](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index) for index sitemaps.

Haven't used that feature before but something like the following would probably work in your case.

```
### sitemaps.py
from django.contrib.sitemaps import GenericSitemap
from models import Section

all_sitemaps = {}
for section in Section.objects.all():

    info_dict = {
        'queryset': section.article_set.filter(is_published=True),
    }

    sitemap = GenericSitemap(info_dict,priority=0.6)

    # dict key is provided as 'section' in sitemap index view
    all_sitemaps[section.name] = sitemap

### urls.py
from sitemaps import all_sitemaps as sitemaps

...
...
...

urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^sitemap.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.index', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
        (r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Django==2.2
Python==3.6
```

Here is the better and easy way to use sitemap index in Django,
install `django.contrib.sitemaps` in the project by adding it to `INSTALLED_APPS` of `settings.py`.
Write sitemaps.py file in your apps and define classes as you need. Example extend `django.contrib.sitemap.Sitemap` in **`StaticViewSitemap`** sitemap class for static URLs, make sure your all static URL has the name for `reverse` lookup(getting URL from URL name)

```
# app/sitemap.py

from django.contrib import sitemaps
from django.urls import reverse

class StaticViewSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):
    priority = 0.6
    changefreq = 'monthly'

    def items(self):
        # URLs names
        return ['index', 'aboutus', 'ourstory',]

    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)
```

Import all sitemaps in urls.py
import sitemap and index from `django.contrib.sitemaps.views`
then create a dictionary with sitemaps

```
# urls.py

from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap, index
from app.sitemaps import StaticViewSitemap

# add as many as sitemap you need as one key
sitemaps = {
    "static" : StaticViewSitemap,
}
urlpatterns = [

    # sitemap.xml index will have all sitemap-......xmls index
    path('sitemap.xml', index, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.index'),

    # sitemap-<section>.xml here <section> will be replaced by the key from sitemaps dict
    path('sitemap-<section>.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```

Here you will have two sitemaps 1. sitemaps.xml 2. sitemaps-static.xml
Run server open URL: http://localhost:8000/sitemap.xml

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap-static.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Django automatically created an index of sitemaps now open URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap-static.xml

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://localhost:8000/</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.6</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://localhost:8000/about-us</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.6</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://localhost:8000/our-story</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.6</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the accepted answer was impacting development and testing cycle speed since it made `python manage.py` commands run more slowly -- I had a little more to do in the DB than this example.

Here are the changes I made to mitigate (adapted to the example).  Have yet to battle test it but this seems to do the trick (Python3):

```
### sitemaps.py

class SitemapLookup():
    """
    Instantiated class replaces the dictionary of {'sitemap-section': Sitemap} for urls.py
    Speeds up application load time by only querying the DB when a sitemap is first requested.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.sitemaps = {}

    def __iter__(self):
        self._generate_sitemaps_dict()
        return self.sitemaps.__iter__()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self._generate_sitemaps_dict()
        return self.sitemaps[key]

    def items(self):
        self._generate_sitemaps_dict()
        return self.sitemaps.items()

    def _generate_sitemaps_dict(self):
        if self.sitemaps:
            return
        for section in Section.objects.all():
            info_dict = {
                'queryset': section.article_set.filter(is_published=True),
            }
            # dict key is provided as 'section' in sitemap index view
            self.sitemaps[section.name] = GenericSitemap(info_dict, priority=0.6)



### urls.py
from sitemaps import SitemapLookup

...
...
...

sitemaps = SitemapLookup()

urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^sitemap.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.index', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
        (r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
)
```